# Acess to the path is denied vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Why I'm i seeing this message.  I just wanted to add the application to start each time with windows and then it popups me this message.

> Access to the path .... is denied.

I add to `startup` with this code

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Dim info As New FileInfo(Application.StartupPath)
       info.CopyTo(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Programs + "\startup\Apps.exe")
    End Sub
```

Comment: It seems you simply don't have the necessary permissions to copy something to that folder.

Comment: @sloth is there any way to avoid that ?

Comment: You need to run your application as administrator.

Comment: @GreenFire i know all that but is there any way to set it through app ?

Comment: Do you really need to copy the .exe? What about an app shortcut?

Comment: How to make it programmatically i just want to my app start with windows. Is there other way ?

Comment: The right way to do it is to use windows registry system

Comment: I made it with this code . Thank you Green Fire i would accept your answer.    `Dim CU As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")
        With CU
            .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

            .SetValue(ApplicationName, ApplicationPath)
        End With`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that your application to start on windows startup you can use the registry.

To add an application to the system use this code -

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Public Sub RunAtStartup(ByVal ApplicationName As String, ByVal ApplicationPath As String)
    Dim CU As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")
    With CU
        .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)

        .SetValue(ApplicationName, ApplicationPath)

    End With
End Sub
```

And to use the function just do -

```
RunAtStartup(Application.ProductName,Application.ExecutablePath)
```